# Magento 2 - Can not get the customer data from customer-data.js file in Magento 2.3.6 p1

Tags: magento2.3, knockoutjs, customer-login, customer-data, undefine

I'm using Magento 2.3.6 p1. And I want to observe the customers when they logged in. I used this in my Js file but it returned undefined when I console.log the first name value. It happened both when customers logged in and logged out.

```
define([
    "jquery", "Magento_Customer/js/customer-data"
], function($, customerData) {
    "use strict";
    return function (config, element) {
        var firstname = customerData.get('customer')().firstname;
        console.log(firstname);
    };
});
```

I have no ideas why this happened. Because I can get the customer data in this way in the older version. Have Magento changed the way to do this, I'm confused.

Answer (score 1):

**You can get firstname using below code:**

```
define([
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'Magento_Customer/js/view/customer'
], function (Component, customerData) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        /** @inheritdoc */
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            this.customer = customerData.get('customer');
        },

        /**
         * @return {*}
         */
        firstname: function() {  
            var customerInfo = customerData.get('customer')();
            var customerFirstname = customerInfo.firstname;
            return customerFirstname
        }  
    });
});
```

Then call firstname where you want to use it